# How do I center this div to keep them to a stacked position when window resized (mobile view)

Tags: html, css, image

Stuck with centering this div (cards) but to keep them to stack when window is resized. It's stacking perfectly but I just cannot center them even with margin right and left being auto.

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/500/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/200/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/900/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/500/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.S013 form .card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.S013 form .card-container .card {
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  margin: 5px;
}

.S013 form .card-container .card .card-body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.S013 form .card-container .card img.card-img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 180px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `.card-container` div a CSS grid property called `justify-content`. It can be `center`, what I think you need in this case if I am correct, especially on larger devices. Read more about `justify-content` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  margin: 5px;
}

.card .card-body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.card img.card-img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 180px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/200/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/900/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/500/?random" alt="Random photo" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Caption 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in css

```
.card {
text-align: center;
}
```